# Nuget push throws 503 unavailable error in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, nuget-push

We are getting **503 service unavailable** error while pushing to azure artifacts, using nuget push command,we are using nugetclicommand task in our yaml pipeline. The push is successful for smaller packages 30mb, but we have errors with the larger ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on package size, the limit is 500mb.

You can check this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/limits?view=azure-devops